# methods from one class to ArrayList in another class

Tags: java

I have a Register class contains 8 sets& gets methods
using:

```
public class Register {
  public Register(String Username) {
   JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
  }

  public void setUname() {
    JoptionPane.showInputDialog(myFrame, "Enter Username");  
  }  

  public String getUname() {
    return  Uname;  
  }
}
```

There are other methods, 8 in total all requiring user input as String or double.

How in another class, can I import the methods into an ArrayList?

```
public class RegisterApp {  
  public addUser() {  
    ArrayList<Register> MyReg = new Arraylist<Register>();  
    myReg.add(Class Register);  
  }
}
```

Uncertain really of what goes after myReg.add

Comment: Not very clear as to what you are trying or asking. but thi s is how you add a new Register instance to ArrayList `myReg.add(new Register());`

Comment: myReg.add(new Register()); adds a register object to the list. It does't call anly of the setters, tho. Not sure what you want to do.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Import methods? Into an instance of ArrayList? And why are there "set" methods using UI? (or are they simply misnamed)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to a `Register`.

```
public  class RegisterApp {
  public addUser() {
    ArrayList<Register> MyReg = new Arraylist<Register>();
    //Make an instance of Register and add it to the list
    myReg.add(new Register("Me"));
  }
}
```

You also mention adding methods to the list. What do you mean by that? What else are you trying to do? Do you want to call those methods on the instances in the list? You can do that like this:

```
for (Register reg : myReg) {
  System.out.println(reg.getUname());
}
```

Note:
Your set method doesn't actually save the value anywhere. You are not storing the result in `uname` (which should be lowecase u). In general, setters are written so they are passed the new value in. This way you are not tied to using an input dialog anytime you change the name. That is a UI decision and should not effect the data model.

```
public void setUname(String uname) {
  this.usname = uname;
}
```

Comment: Thany you for the replies, will have a go int the morning.